# JSF: More customizable selectManyCheckbox and selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf

I'm using selectManyCheckboxes and selectOneRadios and I would like to customize them in some way. It would be sufficient if there was be a possibilty to group the selectItems according to a certain property (e. g. with a headline for each group or a line between each group).

Is there any way to achieve this with standard JSF 2 + Tomahawk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly this is possible. You've already made a good choice with Tomahawk. It's namely one of the very few component libraries which provides components which allows you to position checkboxes and radiobuttons everywhere the way you want instead of ending up with them in a table as the standard components do.

Here's a kickoff example with [`<t:selectOneRadio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) (note the new `layout="spread"` attribute, the JSF defaults are `pageDirection` and `lineDirection`) and [`<t:radio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_radio.html).

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
</t:selectOneRadio>

<p><t:radio for="foo" index="0" /> radio in paragraph</p>
<h1><t:radio for="foo" index="1" /> radio in heading</h1>
<hr />
<p><t:radio for="foo" index="2" /> radio after horizontal rule</p>
```

The [`<t:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectManyCheckbox.html) also supports `layout="spread"` with [`<t:checkbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_checkbox.html) the same way.

This allows for more fine grained HTML/CSS markup on and around those buttons/checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm not sure if this solution suits my needs. I don't know the number and order of the selectItems before runtime, so the index is not very useful to me. My situation is this: I have objects with a property "category" (could be e. g. x, y or z) and I would like to group them according to that property. Can I achieve this with this solution somehow? I don't see how.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, totally missed this one. As to index: you can use `<t:dataList>` to iterate over them with a loop index. As to grouping: this is hard to answer as long as it's not clear how you'd like to have the final HTML to look like, but you could at least conditionally render using `rendered` attribute.