# Apply CSS to <f:selectItem> nested in <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: css, jsf

I want to apply CSS specific to `<f:selectItem>` in `<h:selectOneMenu>` to be displayed in a different style.

e.g. I want every option of coffee in the list below to be displayed in a different color.

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee1}"> 
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Cream Latte"   itemLabel="Coffee3 - Cream Latte" /> 
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Extreme Mocha" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Extreme Mocha" /> 
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Buena Vista"   itemLabel="Coffee3 - Buena Vista" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>`
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 12):

The `<f:selectItem>` renders a HTML `<option>` element. It has very limited CSS styling support. The `color` property is not among them. Even more, it works in MSIE only, not in other webbrowsers. There is however no way to give each `<option>` element its own `style` attribute by JSF, so closest what you can get is applying a CSS rule on all options and accepting that it works in MSIE only.

```
<h:selectOneMenu styleClass="mymenu">
```

with

```
.mymenu option {
    color: red;
}
```

Your best bet is to replace the dropdown by a `<ul><li>` with a good shot of CSS/JavaScript which mimics it to look like a dropdown. Some JSF component libraries has such a component, such as PrimeFaces' `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Check the *Custom content* example in its [3.0 showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf).

Comment: What about `h:selectOneRadio`?  I have a requirement where there are 3 options each of which has a different color label.  Cant find a way to do that with radio in jsf.  It seems to be rendering as a table with an `<input type='radio'>` and a matching `<label for='xxx'>` in each cell.  Seems like they should allow css styles along the same lines as an `h:panelGrid`, but it doesn't appear that they do.  You know of any trick for this?

Comment: @Lucas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033955/jsf-more-customizable-selectmanycheckbox-and-selectoneradio

Comment: Thanks, that will work, but we aren't currently using tomahawk. I will have to see if that can be added to our environment without negative consequences (seems like too many frameworks is a bad thing).  Anyway, I found a hackish way to do it with default jsf:

`<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="choices" layout="lineDirection"><f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="yes" /><f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="no" /></h:selectOneRadio>`

css:
`.choices input[value="yes"] + label {color:green}
.choices input[value="no"] + label {color:red}`

Answer (score -4):

I’m not familar with JSF, but I assume the `<f:selectItem>` is not what gets sent to the browser.

You’ll need to figure out what HTML *is* sent to the browser for that JSF tag, and apply your CSS to that.