# <h:selectOneMenu>-- display an option in different color

Tags: jsf

I have a piece of code

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="addStream" value="#{streamManager.selectedStreamID}"> 
<f:selectItems value="#{streamManager.streamList}" var="stream"  /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

StreamList is the list of all the streams. In a stream bean I have a  boolean attribute isCapacityfull. If isCapacityfull is true I want to show that stream in a red color in the drop down. How can I achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I apply CSS to a JSF <f:selectItem> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747311/how-can-i-apply-css-to-a-jsf-fselectitem-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You can use different css styles and apply them according to the value of the attribute:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{streamManager.streamList}" var="stream" styleClass="#{streamManager.streamList.isCapacityfull ? 'style1' : 'style2' } />
```

Comment: -1: the `<f:selectItems>` doesn't support the `styleClass` attribute and the HTML `<option>` element has very little CSS support anyway. Changing color for example, only works in MSIE.

Comment: If changing color doesnt work, then can we add  a small red bullet for the stream for which  isCapacityfull is true