# Style attribute ignored on PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu component

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.2 and if I add a style attribute to the  tag,

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width: 100%;">
```

it is ignored and the rendered element style contains a (I guess based on the longest option of the list) calculated width style attribute.

Even using the CSS skinning (*.ui-selectonemenu* and *.ui-selectonemenu-label*) of PrimeFaces does not work - it is overwritten by the element style.

The method described here is also not applicable: [Apply CSS to <f:selectItem> nested in <h:selectOneMenu>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747311/how-can-i-apply-css-to-a-jsf-fselectitem-tag)

Maybe this is related to this bug: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4196&q=style&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary

Does anyone encountered the same problem or maybe has some workaround?

Best regards,
Helge

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the problem on PrimeFaces 3.2, but not on PrimeFaces 3.3.1, then my guess is that they fixed it.

It's very likely related to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3885), and even though Cagatay said it doesn't apply to 3.2, I reproduced it just now.

My advice would be for you to update your PrimeFaces version.