# Issue in attribute for on h:outputLabel inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf

I have following piece of code, i want to render radioButtons and labels for them. Due to the layout renderized by selectOneRadio and selectItem i decided to use plain HTML for the input radioButtons.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="6">
    <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.list}" var="item">
        <input id="#{item.innerList[0].id}" type="radio" name="radioItem" value="#{item.innerList[0].id}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="#{item.innerList[0].id}" value="#{item.label}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

When trying to assign a label for them using outputLabel it renders the attribute for in HTML something like:

j_idt94:0:theidiassigned

The prependId flag in the tag form containing this code is set to false and in the documentation there is no such flag in the attributes of the other containing tags of the outputLabel.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `<h:selectOneRadio>`? There are definitely solutions/workarounds, among others Tomahawk `<t:selectOneRadio>`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033955/jsf-more-customizable-selectmanycheckbox-and-selectoneradio/6034020#6034020

Answer (score 2):

The `ui:repeat` component is a [NamingContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html). It controls the [client identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) of its children.

The `for` attribute on a `h:outputLabel` will generally look for a component with a matching component identifier or client identifier.

So, for this markup:

```
<foo:someNamingContainer id="x">
  <h:inputText id="foo" />
  <h:outputLabel for="foo" />
</foo:someNamingContainer>
```

...the label would emit the matching, namespaced identifier `<label for="...:x:foo"`.

There is no matching JSF component with a matching id since you are using a straight XHTML `<input>` element.

Consider just using a XHTML `<label>` element instead.